# How can I perform a fast lookup in an Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]

Tags: scala

How can I perform a lookup from an `Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]` .

I have an array shown below:

```
Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([Aber,Abercrombie], [AbercrombieKids,Abercrombie Kids], [AceHardware,Ace Hardware], [Acme Market,Acme Fresh Market])
```

my input will a String value such as "AbercrombieKids", and if the string gets an exact match with the first index value of the array, then i should get second index value, i.e `Abercrombie Kids` as the output.

Comment: Are you really using Spark? If so, there's not really any good way of looking up a single Row. What's the actual use case? Often you can do (effectively) all the lookups in one go with a join. If not using Spark, this seems an ideal use-case for Map. Just convert the Array to a Map first.

Comment: Hi @TheArchetypalPaul, i am using spark but ideally i don't want to have any joins.

Comment: I'm assuming your array is actually an RDD and so large. If not, broadcast it (converted to a Map) to all nodes. But  it it's "large" then there's no such thing as  a "fast" lookup - the lookup may have to get the result from a different node, and that's *expensive*.  With Spark, however, you rarely want to do just one lookup, you want to do the same thing to all (or many rows).  Usually, that translates to a join or similar. So "I don't want to have any joins" is probably not ideal, at all.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to handle all your scenarios , Please find the below answers with explanation

Input with all scenarios

```
scala> val rowArr=Array(Row("Aber","Abercrombie"), Row("AbercrombieKids","",null,"Abercrombie Kids"), Row("AceHardware","Ace Hardware"),Row(null,"Acme Market","Acme Fresh Market",null),Row(null,null))
rowArr: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([Aber,Abercrombie], [AbercrombieKids,,null,Abercrombie Kids], [AceHardware,Ace Hardware], [null,Acme Market,Acme Fresh Market,null], [null,null])

scala> val matchStr="AbercrombieKids"
matchStr: String = AbercrombieKids
```

Convert `Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]` to `Array[Array[String]]`

```
scala> val arrOfArrStr=rowArr.map(Row=>Row.mkString(",").split(","))
arrOfArrStr: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(Aber, Abercrombie), Array(AbercrombieKids, "", null, Abercrombie Kids), Array(AceHardware, Ace Hardware), Array(null, Acme Market, Acme Fresh Market, null), Array(null, null))
```

Remove `empty` and `null` `Strings` and take the `Arrays` which `length` is greater than 1

```
scala> val arrWithoutNull=arrOfArrStr.map(arr=>arr.filter(str=>str!="null" && str.size>0)).filter(_.length>1)
arrWithoutNull: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(Aber, Abercrombie), Array(AbercrombieKids, Abercrombie Kids), Array(AceHardware, Ace Hardware), Array(Acme Market, Acme Fresh Market))
```

Now, Match your given `String` in `arrWithoutNull` of `Array[Array[String]]` and take only `Arrays` right side to matched `String`

```
scala> val matchedArrStr=arrWithoutNull.filter(_.contains(matchStr)).flatMap(arr=>arr.drop(arr.indexOf(matchStr)+1))
matchedArrStr: Array[String] = Array(Abercrombie Kids)
```

Now take the `head` of `matchedArrStr` if `matchedArrStr` is not `empty`

```
scala> val finalAns=if(matchedArrStr.size>0) matchedArrStr.head else "Match not found"
finalAns: String = Abercrombie Kids
```

I hope this will help you !

Comment: if the array have a null value either in first index or second index, then how to resolve it? and in case i have 3 values in the array and i want to  match the input string with the second index if first index is null and return the 3rd index value how it can be done?

Comment: Hi @Sanjay , I covered all the scenarios. I hope this will help you